# android: why are no elements appearing in my listview?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a ListView as the main navigation feature in a magazine-reader app. I want each View in the list to display the headline of a story below an image associated with it. I have created an XML layout with a vertically-oriented LinearLayout with an ImageView on top and TextView on the bottom, and am trying to create a custom adapter that inflates this layout in the getView method and puts the image/text resources into it. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.caliber;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.caliber.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner issues, sections;
Button blog;
ListView mainGal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] issueList = {"issues", "fall '12", "spring '12", "fall '11", "spring '12", 
                            "fall '10", "spring '10"};
    String[] sectionList = {"sections", "campus", "entertainment", "lifestyle", "love&sex", "tech&web", "Current" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> aaIssues = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spin_item, issueList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aaSections = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
R.layout.spin_item, sectionList);

    blog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blogBtn);

    issues = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.issueSpin);
    sections = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sectionSpin);             
    issues.setAdapter(aaIssues);
    sections.setAdapter(aaSections);


    OnClickListener mbListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
        issues.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
        sections.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
        blog.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
        }
     };


    ImageButton mainbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cbutton);      
    mainbtn.setOnClickListener(mbListener);

    mainGal = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainGal);
    GalAdapter ga = new GalAdapter();
    mainGal.setAdapter(ga);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

class GalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Activity context;
    String[] headlines = {"Alpha bravo charlie delta", "Echo foxtrot golf 
hotel", "indigo juliette kilo lima"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};

    public GalAdapter() {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.galleryview);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         
        View story = li.inflate(R.layout.galleryview, parent);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)story.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView headline = (TextView)story.findViewById(R.id.headline);

        image.setImageResource(images[position]);
        headline.setText(headlines[position]);
        return story;       
}
```

The app launches fine and I can see the listview's background, but there are no items on the list. Why is this? As is probably clear, I'm very new to android development, but have a good understanding of the fundamentals of Java. I'm aware this is due to a fundamental misunderstanding I have here, perhaps an error in one of the constructors (I'm still a little fuzzy on what some of the parameters are). Anyway, I'll be very appreciative if anyone can help me understand these issues more deeply.

Thanks in advance

p.s. is it poor form to categorize this under both android and java? should I just use android in the future?

---EDIT:

```
    class GalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Activity context;
    String[] hlines;
    int[] imgs;

    public GalAdapter(String[] hlines, int[] imgs) {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.galleryview , hlines);
        this.hlines = hlines;
        this.imgs = imgs;
    }       
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context. getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.galleryview, parent);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView headline = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.headline);

        image.setImageResource(imgs[position]);
        headline.setText(hlines[position]);}
        return convertView;                                 
    }
    }
```

Now I'm getting a null pointer exception on the line where I call the LayoutInflator. What pointer is it referring to? I'm assuming I'm not passing the arrays (String[] hlines + int[] imgs) into it properly... Here is where I make the call:

```
    String[] headlines ={ "Echo foxtrot golf hotel", "Echo foxtrot golf hotel", "indigo   
juliette kilo lima"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};
            ....
    mainGal = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainGal);
    GalAdapter ga = new GalAdapter(headlines, images);
    mainGal.setAdapter(ga);
```

Comment: You call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` twice, take that out -it's redundant. Just a code tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is not created properly.  In order to use `ArrayAdapter`, you must either:

1. Supply the list of items to the super implementation
2. Add the items directly to the adapter, or
3. Override all of the methods necessary to categorize the data the adapter holds, such as `getCount()`, `getItem()`, etc.

The simplest fix is to change your constructor like so:

```
public GalAdapter() {
    super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.galleryview, headlines);
}
```

What this does is allows the adapter implementation to use one of your arrays to determine how many items are in the list, and what data it should return when `getItem()` is called.  Since you are overriding `getView()`, the second parameter isn't even really necessary and you could probably get away with `super(MainActivity.this, 0, headlines)` as well.

If your final implementation it to gather data from multiple arrays like this, you may ultimately be better of creating your custom adapter as a subclass of `BaseAdapter` directly, as you are already bypassing most of the functionality `ArrayAdapter` provides as convenience.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks, that's really helpful re: the second parameter, I was thinking that must be the case. I've changed my code but, unfortunately, now I'm getting a null pointer exception. Please see my edit

Comment: That is because the reference `Activity context` in your code is never set to anything, but then you try to call a method on it.  Rather than passing a reference to the Activity, just remove that line and use `getLayoutInflater().inflate()` instead.

Comment: convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.galleryview, parent);            aaaand now I'm getting an Unsupported Operation Exception on that same line...  thanks again for the help, sorry to be such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Nevermind, got it! I needed to change parent to null... not really sure why that worked though, or exactly what i did for that matter?

Comment: Actually the correct change is not to change `parent` to `null`, but rather to add `false` as a third parameter, i.e. `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.galleryview, parent, false)`.  In this case you only want to inflate the layout, not also attempt to attach it.

Comment: Also, you don't want to put ALL your `getView()` code inside the `if` statement.  It's going to work now with only three items, but a list that actually scrolls won't actually load any new data.  You might want to look at an example like this one: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. so that I understand: I'm thinking that the Unsupported Operation Exception was because I was trying to attach the layout to a parent viewgroup that couldn't hold it (or that I hadn't set to anything, but I'd think that'd throw a null pointer exception)... when I use null it tries to attach it to nothing, which it can do without blowing up, but ideally I want to say false so that it won't try to attach it to anything. Correct?

Comment: If the parent parameter is null, it doesn't attempt to attach the two either, which is why it works, but you also don't get to use the parent to properly evaluate the layout params fo the view you are inflating, which is key (that's why the framework gives it to you in the callback).  The UnsupportedOperationException throws when the framework tries to attach the view after you return and it finds out that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here https://github.com/cplain/custom-list it will be able to help you a bit, you need to use `convertView`in your `getView()` and I would advise passing in a list into your adapter not making one inside

Comment: This example uses a bad pattern, you should never pass `null` in `inflate()`.  The reason `getView()` passes in the parent `ViewGroup` is for the sole purpose of you to use it in inflating your child views so that layout parameters are properly evaluated in the process.